# Python pandas sort_values() gives inconsistent result for a column of dataFrame of type String

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame with a column `category`. I need to sort the column case-sensitively. Please find below the sample code.

```
import pandas as pd
import json

pd.set_option("display.max_rows", None, "display.max_columns", None)

json_str = '{"index":{"0":0,"1":1,"2":3,"3":4,"4":5,"5":8,"6":9,"7":11,"8":12,"9":13,"10":14,"11":15,"12":16,"13":17,"14":19,"15":20,"16":22,"17":24,"18":26,"19":27,"20":29,"21":30,"22":31,"23":32,"24":33,"25":34,"26":36,"27":39,"28":41,"29":42,"30":43,"31":44,"32":45,"33":46,"34":47,"35":48,"36":49,"37":51,"38":52,"39":55,"40":56,"41":57,"42":58,"43":60,"44":61,"45":63,"46":64,"47":65,"48":66,"49":67,"50":70,"51":72,"52":73,"53":74,"54":75,"55":78,"56":79,"57":80,"58":82,"59":83,"60":84,"61":85,"62":86,"63":87,"64":89,"65":90,"66":92,"67":94,"68":95,"69":96,"70":97,"71":98,"72":102,"73":105,"74":106,"75":107,"76":108,"77":109,"78":110,"79":111,"80":112,"81":114,"82":115,"83":116,"84":118,"85":119,"86":120,"87":121,"88":122,"89":123,"90":124,"91":126,"92":127,"93":128,"94":129,"95":132,"96":133,"97":134,"98":137,"99":138,"100":140,"101":141,"102":142,"103":144,"104":146,"105":147,"106":148,"107":149,"108":150,"109":152,"110":155,"111":157,"112":160,"113":161},"category":{"0":"MF Purchase","1":"Cash Withdrawal","2":"Transfer to Cred","3":"Transfer to PALI BARM","4":"Loan","5":"Small Savings","6":"Transfer to CTRAZORPAY","7":"Loan","8":"Transfer to EASTERN SERVICE S","9":"Cash Withdrawal","10":"Transfer to PALI BARM","11":"Transfer to Cred","12":"Personal Loan","13":"Transfer to TUHINA K","14":"Transfer to Wallet","15":"Transfer to MONEY VIEW","16":"Transfer to PALI BARM","17":"Transfer to SHANKAR D","18":"Cash Withdrawal","19":"Transfer to EMPIRE","20":"Loan","21":"Loan","22":"Tax","23":"Bank Charges","24":"Cash Withdrawal","25":"Transfer to DELUXE SERVICE","26":"Transfer to Wallet","27":"Cash Withdrawal","28":"Cash Withdrawal","29":"Transfer to PRASENJIT","30":"Transfer to SANJIB BA","31":"Transfer to Wallet","32":"Transfer to Wallet","33":"Cash Withdrawal","34":"Transfer to SHANTANU CARFIL","35":"Transfer to Wallet","36":"Transfer to Wallet","37":"Transfer to EARLYSALA","38":"MF Purchase","39":"Transfer to CRED","40":"Transfer to Kreditzy","41":"Transfer to Kreditzy","42":"Transfer to CTRAZORPAY","43":"Transfer to Mr SOUVIK","44":"Small Savings","45":"Loan","46":"Personal Loan","47":"Transfer to CRED","48":"Transfer to Wallet","49":"Utilities","50":"Transfer to WhizdmInn","51":"Transfer to KOLKATA METRO KAV","52":"Loan","53":"Transfer to TUMI ASBEY BOLE","54":"Transfer to Mahammad","55":"Transfer to khatabook","56":"Utilities","57":"Utilities","58":"Cash Withdrawal","59":"Tax","60":"Bank Charges","61":"Transfer to Wallet","62":"Transfer to Wallet","63":"Transfer to Shivam Ac","64":"Transfer to Wallet","65":"Transfer to Wallet","66":"Transfer to Wallet","67":"Transfer to SOUVIK M","68":"Transfer to HueyTechnolo","69":"MF Purchase","70":"Transfer to RAZORPAY SOFTW","71":"Transfer to Bank Acco","72":"Transfer to Wallet","73":"Transfer to Bank Acco","74":"Transfer to Wallet","75":"Small Savings","76":"Transfer to CTRAZORPAY","77":"Loan","78":"Transfer to SUPRIYA S","79":"Personal Loan","80":"Transfer to Wallet","81":"Cash Withdrawal","82":"Transfer to RazorpayZ","83":"Transfer to Wallet","84":"Transfer to CRED","85":"Transfer to RAJ","86":"Transfer to Mr SOUVIK","87":"Transfer to Mr SOUVIK","88":"Transfer to MONEY VIEW","89":"Loan","90":"Others","91":"Transfer to CRED","92":"Loan","93":"Transfer to GOBARDHAN","94":"Transfer to Mr SOUVIK","95":"Transfer to BIG BAZAAR","96":"Loan","97":"Transfer to Mr SOUVIK","98":"Transfer to delhivery","99":"Transfer to RazorpayZ","100":"Transfer to Mr SOUVIK","101":"Transfer to Mr SOUVIK","102":"Transfer to KOLKATA METRO KAV","103":"Utilities","104":"Cash Withdrawal","105":"Transfer to Wallet","106":"Transfer to WOW MOMO KOLKATA","107":"Utilities","108":"Transfer to SANJIB BA","109":"Cash Withdrawal","110":"Transfer to MD SHAHID","111":"Transfer to GOBARDHAN","112":"Transfer to EarlySala","113":"Others"}}'

df = pd.read_json(json_str)

df.loc[:, 'category'] = pd.Categorical(df['category'], categories=sorted(set(df['category'].tolist()),key=str.lower))

print(df.sort_values(by=['category'])['category'])
```

On running the above code, sorting order is not consistent. It gives inconsistent results on each run. Please find below snippet from the output.

**On First run**

```
91                  Transfer to CRED
47                  Transfer to CRED
39                  Transfer to CRED
84                  Transfer to CRED
11                  Transfer to Cred
2                   Transfer to Cred
```

**On Second/Multiple run**

```
11                  Transfer to Cred
2                   Transfer to Cred
91                  Transfer to CRED
47                  Transfer to CRED
39                  Transfer to CRED
84                  Transfer to CRED
```

Note that sometimes `Transfer to Cred` comes at the top and sometimes it's at the bottom.

**Expected result**

I expect the below output every time I run the code.

```
11                  Transfer to Cred
2                   Transfer to Cred
91                  Transfer to CRED
47                  Transfer to CRED
39                  Transfer to CRED
84                  Transfer to CRED
```

Comment: I dont have such a problem running your code. It gives me expected result all the time

Comment: @Biarys Can you please try to run this say 5-6 times and check if you are getting same result every time.

Comment: I did this in Jupyter notebook and CMD. Jupyter notebook gives expected output consistently. CMD gives first run output consistently. If you are about different results between different environments, perhaps you should convert to the column to lower/upper case and then sort on that

Comment: @Biarys Any specific reason for this difference in behaviour in CMD and Jupyter notebook?

Comment: no idea why it does that